# Is it possible to set gravity programmatically for RecyclerView children in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to set gravity for children in RecyclerView, but it looks like the LayoutParams does not have a gravity method. I have tried the following:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

I have also tried the following:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

In both cases `params.setMargin(int, int, int, int)` works just fine and the margin is set correctly.

My RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/messages_list_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

My RelativeLayout (child of RecyclerView):

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/message_text_wrapper"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/chat_bubble"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:padding="10dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want to be able to do is `params.setGravity(int)` or any other hack that makes this possible. Thanks.

Comment: Does the answer here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426101/set-gravity-programmatically-for-item-in-recycerview-android

Comment: @user4989692 No it does not unfortunately!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your item view inside a FrameLayout, make sure its `layout_width` is set to `match_parent`.

Give your layout which you wrapped in the FrameLayout an id and connect it to your `ViewHolder`.
(I think you've already done this with `@+id/message_text_wrapper`)

Then in `onBindViewHolder` do this:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) holder.yourLayout.getLayoutParams()
if (condition) {
    params.gravity = Gravity.END // or Gravity.RIGHT
} else {
    params.gravity = Gravity.START // or Gravity.LEFT
}
```

Comment: Wrapping layout means redundant parent just for setting gravity. It's not very good from performance stand point, especially for list item.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the `RelativeLayout` in a `FrameLayout` with `android:width="match_parent"` and then set the gravity left/right on the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: This did not work for me, but if you're sure this would work, can you provide example code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using Java inside the onBindViewHolder where I set properties for the TextView

```
`mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`
```

Android Studio will inform you that the property for `Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL` = Int 1 so you can enter the integer instead.

Other properties can be
`Gravity.CENTER` = Int 17
`Gravity.RIGHT` = Int 5
`Gravity.LEFT` = Int 3
`Gravity.TOP` = Int 48
`Gravity.BOTTOM` = Int 80

et-cetera